# Using chrome custom tabs for extrernal urls

Tags: android, android-studio, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using the template from github: [https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView](https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView/)

Actually this app has a option to open urls other than webview url in default browser. Now I want to open them in chrome custom tabs.

Step 1: I enabled it in variables.
static boolean ASWP_EXTURL = true; //open external url with default browser instead of app webview

Step 2: Added dependencies.

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
}
```

Step 3: Added code in MainActivity.java (Refer line 455).

```
//Opening external URLs in android default web browser
        } else if (ASWP_EXTURL && !aswm_host(url).equals(ASWV_HOST)) {
            //aswm_view(url,true);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

// create an intent builder
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

// Begin customizing
// set toolbar colors
intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
intentBuilder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

// set start and exit animations
intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
        android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

// build custom tabs intent
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();

// launch the url
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, uri);

        } else {
            a = false;
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Step 3; Compiled and runned in emulator. The app opens webview urls as usual. But when clicking external urls it hangs and stops.

Anyone please guide me.

Also, I found a bug.
When loading first time, some of my mobile menus not showing correctly. But after a second click(when opening another page) it gets fixed.

References:
My question in Github: https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView/issues/57
https://segunfamisa.com/posts/chrome-custom-tabs
If anyone find mistakes in my question, please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already added customtabs dependency, you can add this to `aswm_view()` inside `if(tab){...` condition:

```
   CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(); 
   intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
   intentBuilder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary)); // better if you replace this with a darker shade
   intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
   intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
   CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
   try {
      customTabsIntent.launchUrl(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(url));
   } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
      startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Once dependency errors fixed (if any), I believe that will be all.